# Is it possible to use the aspectj point cuts for the third party packages(JDBC template)

Tags: spring-mvc, aspectj, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am using Spring JdbcTemplate for connection. I am trying to log the "queries executing" directly from JDBC template using aspectJ.

Is it possible to use the aspectj point cuts for the third party packages(JDBC template) directly in the following way: `@pointcut("execution(* org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations.*(..))")`? When I try this, this pointcut in JDBC operations was not invoked.

I also tried the following: `@Pointcut("execution(* org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.*(..))")`. But still, nothing happened.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this with `Spring AOP`, because it's outside of context of your application, it is on managed by Spring container. Spring AOP is limited to it's own application context, however it is possible with `AspectJ`.

First of all you need to add `AspectJ runtime library` to your project.
Required dependencies :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Next, enable AspectJ nature of your project. I am using STS, so in my case I just `Enable AspectJ tooling`, and it adds `AspectJ` runtime automatically to my project. Right-click on your project -> Spring Tools -> Enable Spring Aspects Tooling

[image]

Make sure AspectJ Runtime Library is on your classpath

[image]

Next add `AspectJ` aspect to your project.

```
public aspect JdbcAspect {

     before(): execution(* org.springframework.jdbc.*.*.*(..)) {
            System.out.println("   ### Intercepted");
        }
}
```